# Phonegap/cordova - window.FirebasePlugin undefined

Tags: firebase, cordova, phonegap

I have been trying to get firebase messaging work for a few days with no luck - I keep getting "window.FirebasePlugin undefined" on window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(); , which is in deviceready ,  when I am running it in phonegap app on my Samsung phone.
Here is my cordova settings:
        cordova-plugin-androidx 1.0.2 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
       cordova-plugin-firebase-lib 5.1.1 "Google Firebase Plugin"
      cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"

cordova-lib@9.0.1 with:
  cordova-common@3.2.0
  cordova-create@2.0.0
  cordova-fetch@2.0.1
  cordova-serve@3.0.0

Environment:
  OS: win32
  Node: v10.16.3
  npm: 6.9.0

"cordova build android" runs successfully.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) as `cordova-plugin-firebase-lib` is archived.

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase-lib --save
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex --save
```

If that didn't work, I recommend to install everything again as mentioned in their documentation:

```
rm -Rf platforms/android
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase
rm -Rf plugins/ node_modules/
npm install
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: Created new app from scratch with cordova-plugin-firebasex - still same error :\

Comment: Is there any errors in the console? You can check it like this: https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/debugging-an-ionic-android-app-using-chrome-dev-tools-6e139b79e8d2

Comment: Getting "D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///data/user/0/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/js/index.js: Line 69 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined"